# jQuery images and the if/else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, if-statement

trying to hide/show div based on what images our visible.
The "else" statement works but not the "if"

```
$(document).click(function() {  

    var t1 = document.getElementById("tpart1");     
    var t2 = document.getElementById("tpart2");     

    if (t1.src == 'images/team/bev_01.jpg' && t2.src == 'images/team/bev_02.jpg') {
        $("#bevbio").show("slow")    
    }

else {
        $("#annettebio").hide("slow")
        $("#bevbio").hide("slow")
        $("#keithbio").hide("slow")
        $("#krisbio").hide("slow")
        $("#mikebio").show("slow")
    }
});
```

Comment: Well...does `t1`'s and `t2`'s src match what the `if` statement says?

Comment: This is where debugging saves you. `console.log()` the two sources and see if they are what you're expecting in your if statement.

Comment: Don't understand why you're mixing jQuery and vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `src` property will always be an absolute URL; you're testing the attribute, so you'd need:

```
t1.getAttribute('src')
```

Comment: You're quite welcome, I'm glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this too

```
if (t1.src.indexOf('images/team/bev_01.jpg') > 0 && t2.src.indexOf('images/team/bev_02.jpg') > 0) {
        $("#bevbio").show("slow")    
    }
```